# Limiting mysql database size

Tags: mysql, mysql-5.7

What is best way to limit mysql database size? Is it possible to limit database a to 200mb and database b to 300mb?

Comment: What do you expect to happen when you insert a new row that causes the database to exceed the size limit? Are temporary tables included in the limit you set? What about logs?

Comment: Refuse to write

Comment: No way on DBMS level. Easily on OS level (quoting folder size). But it will cause MySQL server fail.

Comment: @Akina then how companies like ovh sets quotas for their shared hosting services?

Comment: Ask their support.

Comment: @Akina their support not gonna tell: 1stly because they don't know as their knowledge somewhat equals to my mother's one.

Comment: Shared hosting service generally run a script like [this query](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9620198/how-to-get-the-sizes-of-the-tables-of-a-mysql-database) and introduce an account suspension when the limit is hit. They might also just test the directory usage.